# How to stop certain functions and variables being accessed from a particular function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making a game where the player will write their own AI for a robot using JS, which works but they could also access the functions/variables from the actual game, such as the actual player's position. I only want them to be able to access some certain functions, such as `accelerate()` and `turnRight()`. I thought that, before I actually load their AI, I could check and see if it's okay, but there would still be ways to get around it, and there must be a better way - is there one, or would I have to check each bit of code and see if it's allowed?

EDIT: The code for the main game:

- Sets up the scene
- Makes the player and some enemies
- Makes some functions

The actual AI is stored in another file: `AI.js` and in that is a function called `doAI()` which the player will use to make an AI.

Comment: You can write private functions in JS... Just do not expose them!

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work...?

Comment: Also - why vote down? I think it's a perfectly good question

Comment: Downvoter may not feel the same... Also share the code while posting question... Difficult to assume many things...  When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers [_if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'll edit the question then

Comment: Google the Module Pattern

Comment: Search SO with keywords such as "javascript sandbox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
// Your full api
function API() {}
API.prototype.accelerate = function(){/* your logic */}
API.prototype.turnRight = function(){/* your logic */}
API.prototype.privateMethod = function(){/* your logic */}

function wrapAPI(api) {
    // here you make proxy functions for methods you need. api object stored in closure and can't be accessed by user
    return {
        accelerate: function(){ return api.accelerate.apply(api, arguments) },
        turnRight: function(){ return api.turnRight.apply(api, arguments) }
    }
}

var api = new API(); // full API instance

var playerApi = wrapAPI(api); // object with restricted API
```

The main downside of this kind solution is that you make method instance for each of your wrapping object

Comment: I don't get how I'd use this?

Comment: You can give you players `playerApi` objects, so that they can only call restricted set of API functions. I don't know your architecture, it was just an answer to the question "I only want them to be able to access some certain functions"

Comment: Okay I suppose that would work, thanks!